# Vim's key mapping behaving differently between gui mode and cli mode

Tags: vim

I've been trying to figure this out for so long but still failed, some of my customized key-mapping (majority of them are for plugins) behaves totally different between gui-mode and cli-mode, even if I use gui-mode command with `-v` flag (like `mvim -v`) or using `:gui` command in terminal Vi.

For example, the Emmet plugin which is handy for expanding HTML/CSS expressions, the default trigger key `<C-y>` never works at first (in Cli-mode which I often used to), I always don't know why, until one day I use MacVim for a while and suddenly find out it works!

After that, I try to re-map the default trigger from `<C-y>` to `<C-e>` or `<C-k>`, both of them works fine in MacVim but still unlucky in terminal Vim.

Is there any particular reason to cause this issue? Maybe something wrong with my configuration?

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I can get a mapping for <C-y> to work in both terminal Vim and MacVim (well, technically both MacVim, but in both GUI and terminal modes). Could you maybe mention what plugins you have installed?

Comment: Too many to list them, maybe 20+ to 30. So you think it might be conflicting with other plugins? I'll try to disable other plugins and see what is happening then. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @ebenezer OMG... I disable all other plugins except for Emmet, dosen't work. I create a brand new .vimrc and only install Emmet, now it works. That means something wrong with my other configurations...OMG, to many of them...wish my luck, I'm going to fix this...OMG!

Comment: No problem. I just saw your replies here, and I see from below that you figured it out — yay! :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it by myself, but thank for @ebenezer 's reminding.

We often use `set timeoutlen` and `set ttimeoutlen` to tweak the latency for a key code or a mapping sequence to complete. Most of us can't tolerate with the default value for `ttimeoutlen` (which is `-1`), because it forces us to waiting for so long when quit from Insert mode by press `ESC` or `Ctrl-[`.

For this particular reason, I changed this value to `10` (in ms), but I copy this setting from somewhere I don't remember now, and it place `set ttimeoutlen` in a `autocmd` for all filetypes, like below:

```sh
if ! has('gui_running')
  set ttimeoutlen=10
  autocmd InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=0
  autocmd InsertLeave * set timeoutlen=1000
endif
```

I don't know why this will make some plugins not work properly, and I change it a little to make it works for me now:

```sh
if ! has('gui_running')
  autocmd InsertEnter * set ttimeoutlen=100
  autocmd InsertLeave * set ttimeoutlen=-1
endif
```

Hope this will help you if you encounter same problems.